# Operações simbólicas no R

Tags: r

Preciso multiplicar duas matrizes no `R`, uma possui entradas simbólicas (*beta*) e a outra é uma matriz numérica (*X*), já tentei os pacotes `Ryacas` e `rSymPy`, mas não consegui fazer funcionar. Após isso, preciso de derivar a função *f* em relação a *beta0* e depois em relação a *beta1*. abaixo está o código:

```
library(Deriv)
library(Ryacas)
#library(rSymPy)
n=2
#Vetor de 1's
const1 <- rep(1,n);
const <- cbind(const1);
#Vetor de cováriavel com distribuição unif(0,1)
X1=matrix(runif(n, 0, 1),nrow=n,ncol=1)
#Matriz de covariáveis
X <-matrix(c(const,X1),nrow=n,ncol=ncol(X1)+1)
p=ncol(X)
beta0 <- Sym("beta0")
beta1 <- Sym("beta1")
alpha <- Sym("alpha")
y <- Sym("y")
beta=matrix(c(beta0,beta1),nrow=2,ncol=1)
mu1=exp(X%*%beta)
f <- quote(mu1*y^2+mu1*alpha)
f1 <- Deriv(f,"beta0")
f2 <- Deriv(f,"beta1")
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso proceder esses cálculos?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com esses pacotes nem com valores simbólicos muito menos Yacas, mas pelo que vi você não vai conseguir transformar uma matriz em um objeto Sym, pois ele deve ser sempre de comprimento 1. Para criar matrizes, parece haver uma notação específica. Sugiro que você leia o manual e a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/vignettes/Ryacas.pdf) do pacote.